# C++ Inheritance virtual function crashing

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have got no idea why this code is crashing, it looks correct to me, but it just crashes with a `SIGSEV`. I come from Java and am used to "helpful" error messages...

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "DuckV.h"
#include "PenguinV.h" 

bool tryFlyOOP(IBird* birdy)
{
    return birdy->canFly();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   DuckV* duckV;
   PenguinV* penguinV;

    printf("My OOP duck %s fly\n", tryFlyOOP(duckV) ? "can" : "can't");
    printf("OOP Penguins %s fly\n", tryFlyOOP(penguinV) ? "can" : "can't");

    return 0;
}
```

IBird:

```
#ifndef IBIRD_H
#define IBIRD_H

class IBird
{
public:
    IBird () {}
    virtual bool canFly() {return true;};
};

#endif  /* IBIRD_H */
```

DuckV/PenguinV are the same besides the name and the return value

```
#ifndef DUCKV_H
#define DUCKV_H

#include "IBird.h"

class DuckV : public IBird
{
public:
    DuckV(){}
    virtual bool canFly() {return true;}
};

#endif  /* DUCKV_H */
```

I have tried changing stuff around and I just don't get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Read that SIGSEV as a NullPointerException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized your pointers:

```
DuckV* duckV; // points to a random location. No DuckV object exists.
```

I suggest you drop the pointers and do something like this:

```
bool tryFlyOOP(const IBird& birdy)
{
    return birdy.canFly();
}
```

then

```
DuckV duckV;
std::cout << "My OOP duck " << (tryFlyOOP(duckV) ? "can" : "can't") << " fly\n";
```

This will require that you make your `canFly()` member function `const`:

```
class IBird
{
public:
    IBird () {}
    virtual bool canFly() const {return true;};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your objects are not created.

You should do :

```
DuckV* duckV = new DuckV();
PenguinV* penguinV = new PenguinV();
```

In your code you just declared the pointers.

or you can do :

```
DuckV duckV;
PenguinV penguinV;

bool tryFlyOOP(const IBird& birdy)
{
    return birdy.canFly();
}
```

In then last example you use reference, who is a good way to do this too.

Answer (score 0):

You have not not initialized your variables ( duckV and penguinV). Since you want to use them as pointers, create new objects using the "new" operator and assign it to those variables. Or - better else - create them on the stack and pass a reference.